# Recompile an Oracle package while it is still in running status

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

The Oracle package has one procedure call TestA, and it is very time consuming, about around 3 minutes to finish.

There is one windows job wrriten in C#, who is invoking this Oracle package and the TestA procedure. While the procedure is still in running status, if someone recompile the  Oracle package in PL/SQL, will it affect the normal running result of this windows job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't, because the package can't be compiled if it is in use. Compile attempt will "hang" until the package is "released".

Answer (score 1):

Once if the package starts running you should not touch it or do any compilation.

If you try to compile it on running time it will get hang, until the process gets released the compilation process won't happen.